# Crash after mInterstitialAd.show();

Tags: android

I am a beginner developer. Have got the following problem:

After
`mInterstitialAd.show()` - the application show addon. After addon has been shown the application crashes in some cases.

Addon implementation is the following:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(180000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MainActivity.handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();

                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}).start();
```

The program crashes in RecyclerView.ViewHolder (ViewPager2 is implemented).

Exactly when the application has focused on the Textview field and after addon is started and addon close button is pressed.

TextView instance listener is implemented in ViewPager2.

```
counterName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean lostFocus) {

                    if(!MainActivity.menuOpened) {

CounterList.get(getAdapterPosition()).name = counterName.getText().toString();  crashs here.
}
                }
            });
```

Comment: post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved by try/catch.